# how to read/write a file in c# at same time?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a csv file to be created in two steps:

In the first step, I add two columns in the output.csv file

```
col1,col2
col1,col2
...
```

Then, add two more columns in the same output.csv file

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3,col4
...
```

Because I can not combine the two steps, I need to write to file, and write again from beginning.

Comment: Strange question.  An obvious solution, without knowing why it was asked, is to write two files.

Answer (score 2):

```
var stream = File.Open("output.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
// write file first time here.
stream.Position = 0;
// read stream again here.
stream.Position = column3Position;
// write additional columns in corresponding positions.
```

But this is a clunky way of doing things. Can't you build up a representation of the csv file in an object model (which can be added to at each stage of your process), and then just serialize it to disk all at once?